# After turning on stuck at Started Daemon for power management

Tags: photoshop

After starting up my computer I get a black screen with [ OK ] and messages, it stops after [ OK ] Started Daemon for power management. Main thing I did before turning off, is installing a Photoshop on playonlinux. I'm a layman, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: how long did you wait after the last [OK]?

Comment: Over 10 minutes

Comment: did you do anything else other than install photoshop?

Comment: not really, I used it a little bit, but before Playonlinux asked me to install many files so Photoshop could work (it was originally from exe file), unfortunately I don't remember what they were. After using it for some time I had a bug (image stuck on my screen constantly) that's why I restarted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)